# Implementing multiple interfaces with Java - is there a way to delegate?

Tags: java, interface, delegation

I need to create a base class that implements several interfaces with lots of methods, example below.

Is there an easier way to delegate these method calls without having to create a horde of duplicate methods?

```
public class MultipleInterfaces implements InterFaceOne, InterFaceTwo {

    private InterFaceOne if1;
    private InterFaceTwo if2;

    public MultipleInterfaces() {
      if1 = new ImplementingClassOne();
      if2 = new ImplementingClassTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public void classOneMethodOne { if1.methodOne(); }
    @Override
    public void classOneMethodTwo { if1.methodTwo(); }
    /** Etc. */


    @Override
    public void classTwoMethodOne { if2.methodOne(); }
    @Override
    public void classTwoMethodTwo { if2.methodTwo(); }
    /** Etc. */

}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

As said, there's no way. However, a bit decent IDE can autogenerate delegate methods. For example Eclipse can do. First setup a template:

```
public class MultipleInterfaces implements InterFaceOne, InterFaceTwo {
    private InterFaceOne if1;
    private InterFaceTwo if2;
}
```

then rightclick, choose *Source > Generate Delegate Methods* and tick the both `if1` and `if2` fields and click *OK*.

See also the following screens:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks to BalusC and Lukas for such quick and useful answers. My project is based in Eclipse, so I was able to use BalusC's answer in near real-time ! Worked like a charm, and saved me several hours of frustrating work. As a new user of this forum, I am suprised and delighted at the quality of the participants here.

Comment: Great hint! I didn't know that and will save 100's of hours in the future :) The good thing about stackoverflow: you'll also learn from questions you didn't ask yourself!

Answer (score 7):

**There is one way to implement multiple interface.**

Just extend one interface from another or create interface that extends predefined interface
Ex:

```
public interface PlnRow_CallBack extends OnDateSetListener {
    public void Plan_Removed();
    public BaseDB getDB();
}
```

now we have interface that extends another interface to use in out class just use this new interface who implements two or more interfaces

```
public class Calculator extends FragmentActivity implements PlnRow_CallBack {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    }

    @Override
    public void Plan_Removed() {

    }

    @Override
    public BaseDB getDB() {

    }
}
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately: NO.

We're all eagerly awaiting the Java support for [extension methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-extension-methods)

Answer (score 0):

There's no pretty way. You might be able to use a proxy with the handler having the target methods and delegating everything else to them. Of course you'll have to use a factory because there'll be no constructor.