# Is there a better way to write this (collection) Helper class

Tags: java, collections

I want to know if there is a better way to write the following class

```
public class Helper
{
    public static boolean isMatch(final Collection<ClassA> customList)
    public static boolean containsProperty(final Collection<ClassA> customList, final String property)
}
```

The way the method is called is:

```
Helper.isMatch(customList);
```

What I would like to do is make the call as:

```
customList.isMatch();
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you want extension methods such as are available in c#.  This question covers some options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-extension-methods

Comment: what is isMatch supposed to do?

Comment: The only way I see is composition here.

Comment: @Farzad It doesn't matter what isMatch is doing.  The point is that all the methods in this class will be working on Collection<ClassA>.  So, I am trying to make the code easier to write for someone using this class

Comment: @ChrisFarmer  Thanks Chris.  I think C# is where I might have gotten the inspiration from.  I will check the other post.  Thanks

Comment: Why call it Helper? That could be anything.. Is the namespace include ?.collections.Helper? If not it's not a very good class name.

Comment: @MattWolfe  This is just a sample code.

Comment: @fge I am not sure how composition will make it such that I don't have to pass the collection as a parameter.

Comment: @PranavShah I meant decoration, sorry

Comment: @PranavShah It does matter what "isMatch" is doing.  You are using generics.  Does "isMatch" behave differently depending on whether it is a Collection<ClassA> or a Collection<ClassB>?  Your implementation will be different if you want these methods to behave different depending on what the generic type is.

Comment: @RickGrashel  It is always ClassA.

Comment: Ok, in that case you can just create MyList and have it extend ArrayList (or whatever collection you prefer).  Add your custom methods to that class and enjoy the fact that you inherit all of the other base methods from a Java list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Guava, you can use, for instance, [ForwardingList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingList.html).

It forwards all default `List` method to the embedded instance, and you can add your own.

More details [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html).

Comment: Wiki [link](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained) for Collection Helpers