# Extend android.net.wifi.WifiManager

Tags: java, android

I want to extend [android.net.wifi.WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) .
Since extension methods does not exists for Java I wanted to extend the class itself.

I am however unable to do so, the WiFiManager constructor demands IWifiManager and that interface seems to be hidden.

What am I missing here, How can I extend the WiFiManager?

Comment: try to compose your own class that _uses_ WifiManager instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-extension-methods?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Muharrem Rambo, I know, I pointed that out in the question as background information.

Comment: Don L. Of course I could do that, but that would require more time than I have free on my hands right now, thus I wanted to extend the class itself. The alternatives I'm forced to feels awkward and clumsy with my .net background where this sort of thing feels to smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I extend the WiFiManager?

You can't, for the reasons you cited. They really should have marked the class as `final`.