# Java : How to extend a class and use a dot notation on its object

Tags: java, class, extend

Take for example the class JSONObject.

And say I have the following method.

```
public JSONObject getObjectOrThrow(String name) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = null;
      try {
         jsonObject = JSON.getJSONObject(name);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("JSON_ERROR : " + name);
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return jsonObject;
   }
```

How do I extend the **JSONObject** so that I'll end up with a method like.

```
JSONObject man = new JSONObject("name");
man.getObjectOrThrow("name");
```

Where "name" is the key to the child node of "man".

Also for reference, what is this called?

Comment: How is this related to *extending* a class? You're not even using the child class.

Comment: @Tom Ok, seems I'm even way off the road then, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Since it is currently unclear (at least to me) what you're trying to achieve, no I can't give any hints right now.

Comment: Too bad [Java don't have extension methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979/java-equivalent-to-c-sharp-extension-methods)

Comment: @Relm you wanted to hide the exception handling to a custom method by overriding the functionality ? Just by creating another class ? Is that your question ?

Comment: @VinayVeluri in this case that's what should happen, but I wrote this as an example so that the answer is not limited to this. All I want is : `existingKnownObject.myCustomMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

Custom Class

```
public class CustomJSONObjectProvider extends JSONObject {
    public JSONObject getObjectOrThrow(String name) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = null;
      try {
         jsonObject = JSON.getJSONObject(name);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("JSON_ERROR : " + name);
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return jsonObject;
   }

   // all the other custom methods that you want to override

}
```

And the way you use it

```
CustomJSONObjectProvider customJSONObjectProvider = new CustomJSONObjectProvider();
JSONObject jsonObject = customJSONObjectProvider.getObjectOrThrow("name");
```

It can also be static

```
public class CustomJSONObjectProvider extends JSONObject {
    public static JSONObject getObjectOrThrow(String name) {
      JSONObject jsonObject = null;
      try {
         jsonObject = JSON.getJSONObject(name);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("JSON_ERROR : " + name);
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return jsonObject;
   }

   // all the other custom methods that you want to override

}
```

Its usage

```
JSONObject jsonObject = CustomJSONObjectProvider.getObjectOrThrow("name");
```

Comment: So then I have to pass **JSON** in `JSON.getJSONObject(name)` to CustomJSONObjectProvider. The reason I wanted to do this was so that I never have to pass the object to this class. Thought the Dot Notation would get which object I'm referring to.

Comment: @Relm What is object there ? You wanted to extend the method and provide custom code. What do you mean by `Dot notation will get which object you refer to` ?