# How can I do this in Java? (REL. TO FUNCTIONS)

Tags: java, string

How can I make a function like `String.toUpperCase()` , where suppose I make a function `Character.isVowel()`

Where, I'll simply have to write `'A'.isVowel()` and get a boolean result; just like `"code".toUpperCase();`
which gives me output , `CODE`.

Only if possible ; can you tell me how can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this by extending `Character` because it is a final class (you cannot extend it), but even if you could, you could not just simply cast for example your character to the subclass (you would had to make a corresponding constructor for example).

You could however try something like:

```
public class Main {

    //Supports only english vowels (uperrcase, or lowercase):
    public static boolean isVowel(final int codePoint) {
        return "aeiouyAEIOUY".indexOf(codePoint) >= 0;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isVowel('A')); //true.
        System.out.println(isVowel('b')); //false.
    }
}
```

but again you will have to define all the vowels of all languages manually (both uppercase and lowercase).

I also checked [regexes in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but did not find anything about a *Vowel* class for example.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to know. If you only want to create a upper case string out of a lower case string use `toUpperCase()`. Or do you want to know how to extend the String class? Suraj Gautam answerd this question in the comments:

> String is an immutable class. You cannot extend it.

Comment: Hello my friend, String is an immutable class. You cannot extend it.

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I didn't thought about that. I will improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Methods that look like instance methods although they are not part of the actual class are called "Extension methods". Java does currently not support them. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359979).